# create image from a vhd using azure-sdk-for-java

Tags: java, image, azure, vhd

I used [azure-storage-java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java) to upload a vhd page blob to my storage account from a java application. But to create a virtual machine out of it using ARM template, the vhd should either be registered as an image or a disk, so that it shows up in image gallery while creating a vm. Is there any example of creating an image from a blob, programmatically using azure-sdk-for-java?

Comment: @J.Chomel, let me rephrase my question a bit, if i was not clear. I want my uploaded vhd to show up in image gallery, when i try to create a vm out of it. So, i want to 'register that vhd blob as an image' programmatically, using azure-sdk-for-java

Comment: OK, my bad. removed.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example for creating VM using Azure SDK for Java, please see https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/0.9/azure-mgmt-samples/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/samples/compute/CreateVMExample.java.

To understanding the example, you can refer to the section [Create a Virtual Machine](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-java-sdk/#create-a-virtual-machine) of the offical article `"Azure Resource Manager SDK for Java"`.

As references, you can refer to these [source codes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/0.9/resource-management/azure-mgmt-utility/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/utility) on GitHub for understanding the help classes in the example code, such as `ComputerHelper` & `ResourceContext`.

Answer (score 0):

@harshitha,
AFAIK,Currently Azure doesn't have the `SDK/API` to convert `VHD` as `Image` in ARM.We can operate it on Azure Portal or using Powershell. 
Another approach is that we can use `Create VM Image REST API` to create a VM Image in the image repository that is associated with the specified subscription using a specified set of virtual hard disks(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn775054.aspx ). You could call this REST API with Java code in your project. And then use the Peter pan's code sample to create your VM. Hope it helps.